# convert GMT time to local

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I got the time in GMT format in my iphone project using the following code.But I want to convert it into local time.Please give some ideas to solve this.Thanks in advance.

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

        NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
        [dateFormatter release];
```

Am using GMT format for sending it to server.So first i want it in GMT format only.Afterthat i want to convert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this method to convert current time to GMT

```
    +(NSDate *)getCurrentGMTTime
    {
        NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        NSInteger seconds = -[tz secondsFromGMTForDate: [NSDate date]];
        return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: seconds sinceDate: [NSDate date]];
    }
```

And then use this method to convert GMT time back to local time. Pass your GMT NSDate to this method.

```
    +(NSDate *)getLocalTimeWithDate:(NSDate*)date
    {
        NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
        return [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds sinceDate: date];
    }
```

Comment: How we use the second Code in a Function Void ??

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more, what you want here. Thanks

Comment: I have an NSString = @"2015-06-25T18:00:00Z" it's a GMT time ! And I get my local time (it means how to convert the NSString above to another NSString with the local time zone of the iPhone) ? How can I do that with your method ?

Comment: It is always safe to use NSDate while converting GMT to local or local to GMT. In your case I would suggest use NSDateFormatter and convert your string GMT time to NSDate and then pass it to second function to get local NSDate. Then convert that local NSDate to your desired format of string by NSDateFormatter again.

Answer (score 2):

An NSDate is a fixed point in time in UTC/GMT.

You should always be storing your NSDates that way. When you show a time then you worry about the locale and the timezone.

There is a difference between an NSDate and the way you **display** an NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];`
 
to get your local timezone

Or - taken from the comment

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSString *gmtDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];

NSString *currentDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
[dateFormatter release]
```

Comment: Am using GMT format for sending it to server.So first i want it in GMT format only.Afterthat i want to convert it.

Comment: NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

        NSString *gmtDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

        NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; [dateFormatter setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];

        NSString *currentDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
        [dateFormatter release];

Comment: @AhmedZ. Don't you think your answer would be more readable if you edited your question and put it in with formatting?

Comment: @Abizern there wasnt space left in the comment to do any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line -

```
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

with -

```
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

---

```
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

        NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];

        NSTimeZone *localTZ = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:localTZ];

        NSString *localTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
        [dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: ... but don't call it `gmt` then :-)

Comment: if you need first in GMT then use your code, after that set timezone again with localTimeZone

Answer (score 0):

```
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    [dateFormatter release];
```